# Gedit problems with python

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, gedit

I'm just learning Python in school and we were suppose to draw something (code it in gedit for python) on canvas (Tkinter). Instead of getting something drawn up I only get an empty canvas. [It looks like this on my computer](https://db.tt/X2vvLfQ9). The code is correct as I copied it from another web page.

```
from Tkinter import *

master=Tk()

w=Canvas(master, width=200, height=100)
w.pack

w.create_line(0,0,200,100)
w.create_line(0,100,200,0, fill="red", dash=(4,4))

w.create_rectangle(50,25,150,75, fill="blue")

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the code is *not* correct.  The person who wrote it forgot to actually call the [`pack`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) method. You need to add `()` after it to do this:

```
from Tkinter import *

master=Tk()

w=Canvas(master, width=200, height=100)
########
w.pack()
########

w.create_line(0,0,200,100)
w.create_line(0,100,200,0, fill="red", dash=(4,4))

w.create_rectangle(50,25,150,75, fill="blue")

mainloop()
```

Otherwise, the canvas will never be placed on the window.

P.S.  You should note that not everything you find on the Web is guaranteed to be correct. :)

Comment: Awesome, thank! I was so stressed out over this in class I overlooked the simplest solution! :D